# Heap takes huge jump despite a lot of freed memory - Android

Tags: android, memory-management, heap-memory, dalvik

Could someone explain the following to me!

In my App that displays heavy images, at least some of them. One occupies approx. 63 MB of RAM. (3000 * 5333 * 4) 4 is for 4 channels - Red, Green, Blue and Transparency. Due to this I have to set heap to large in the manifest. So for my Samsung Galaxy S3 I have 304 MB of Heap to play with.

So what I dont understand is how the Dalvik thinks when it allocates memory for the images. You can see how the Heap takes HUGE jumps att certain points.

When stresstesting the app I play around by clicking on the heaviest images. The app soon occupies 111 MB of RAM and stays there for a while . 69 MB is Free.
THEN - when I choose to click on the heavy image of 63 MB, I thought that it would fit into the 69 MB free space - but NOT!!!! Instead it takes a huge leap to 172 MB allocated. I do not understand here how the Dalvik works - 69 MB is free and the image more than well fits into this space - all the same the app jumps to 172 MB.

Glad for answers!!!

```
02-15 21:32:18.254: D/dalvikvm(29897): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
02-15 21:32:18.259: D/dalvikvm(29897): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
02-15 21:32:18.299: D/dalvikvm(29897): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2936K, 63% free 43408K/114311K, paused 11ms+4ms, total 36ms
02-15 21:32:18.344: D/tag(29897): debug. =================================
02-15 21:32:18.344: D/tag(29897): debug.heap native: allocated 4,92MB of 5,11MB (0,17MB free)
02-15 21:32:18.344: D/tag(29897): debug.memory: allocated: 111,00MB of 304,00MB (69,00MB free)
02-15 21:32:18.344: I/System.out(29897): View = android.widget.ScrollView@41f29be8
02-15 21:32:18.424: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29897): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-15 21:32:18.424: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29897): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-15 21:32:26.199: D/dalvikvm(29897): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 220K, 62% free 43496K/114311K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
02-15 21:32:26.284: I/dalvikvm-heap(29897): Grow heap (frag case) to 104.370MB for 63996016-byte allocation
02-15 21:32:26.314: D/dalvikvm(29897): GC_CONCURRENT freed 24K, 41% free 105968K/176839K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 31ms
02-15 21:32:26.724: D/tag(29897): debug. =================================
02-15 21:32:26.724: D/tag(29897): debug.heap native: allocated 5,04MB of 5,16MB (0,12MB free)
02-15 21:32:26.724: D/tag(29897): debug.memory: allocated: 172,00MB of 304,00MB (69,00MB free)
```

the row when I click on the 63 MB image corresponds to the following line in logcat

```
02-15 21:32:26.284: I/dalvikvm-heap(29897): Grow heap (frag case) to 104.370MB for 63996016-byte allocation
```

Comment: I guess the free space is memorymapped that is ready to be used. And maybe Dalvik thinks - **hmmm this app uses heavy images so a lot of free allocated memorymapped pages has to be there, prepared for new images.** . there is a lot of timeoverhead in memorymapping so I guess it may be the answer?

Comment: Did you try doing a search for "android Grow heap (frag case)"?